# Loop through an Associative Arrays after parsing an XML document

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, xml, associative-array

I used a Class to parse an XML-file. The XML-file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
   <name id="1">John Mal</name>
   <addr>123 N 45</addr>
   <phone id="5">555.55.222</phone>
</user>
```

The result of parsing is an -associative Arrays:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => USER
        [content] =>
        [child] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [name] => NAME
                [attrs] => Array([ID] => 1)
                [content] => John Mal
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [name] => ADDR
                [content] => 123 N 45
            )
            [2] => Array(
                [name] => PHONE
                [attrs] => Array([ID] => 5)
                [content] => 555.55.222
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My problem is how to traverse the array and get the information inside. For example I want to get the first `id` and the content of the `name`-tag and so one in a separate lines because after that I want to write all the information in a text-file. How to do that? Any help is very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd vote for a parser like `DOM` or `SimpleXml` for powerful features over an array. If you have to use the array though...

this is how to access a specific datum in your complex array directly:

```
var_dump($a[0]['child'][0]['content']);
```

Output:

```
string(8) "John Mal"
```

Iteration:

```
foreach ($a as $set) {

    echo $set['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo $set['content'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "----------------" . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($set['child'] as $item) {

        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {

            echo "$key: $value" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
USER
CONTENT
----------------
name: NAME
attrs: Array
content: John Mal
name: ADDR
content: 123 N 45
name: PHONE
attrs: Array
content: 123.345
```

see it in action and play around with it: https://eval.in/530409

Answer (score 0):

That parse function doesn't look particular useful for what you're trying to achieve.
You *might* be interested in [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/simplexml) instead.

```
<?php
$user = new SimpleXMLElement(data());
echo 'name=', $user->name,' id=', $user->name['id'], PHP_EOL;
echo 'addr=', $user->addr, PHP_EOL;
echo 'phone=', $user->phone,' id=', $user->phone['id'], PHP_EOL;



function data() {
    return <<< eox
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
   <name id="1">John Mal</name>
   <addr>123 N 45</addr>
   <phone id="5">555.55.222</phone>
</user>
eox;
}
```

Comment: `@VolkerK` Is it possible to get the info from the result I posted?

Comment: `@VolkerK` Your suggestion is good. I want to use a Class to parse the XML-document. The XML-doc posted is just an example because I am trying to parse much bigger and complicated XML(imsmanifest). The Calss I used is fine, but it gives an Array I cannot understand.

Comment: Does this "Class" do anything else but produce this kind of arrays? Is it in any way, shape or form specialized for an imsmanifest?